# Is it still necessary to check an object for nullity if it is initialized using Dagger2?

Tags: android, firebase, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have an `AppModule` class where I have the following method that return a `FirebaseUser` object that I want to be available across my whole life-cycle of my app. Before using dependency injection I have used this code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Is it still necessary to check for nullity like this:

```
@Inject FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

//In onCreate()
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: What does your provider method look like? Does it return a nullable object?

Comment: Hi. No, it should return the current logged-in user. The question is, is it still necessary to check for `null` since it is already initialized at runtime?

Comment: If you are sure that your provider _never_ returns `null` despite that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` actually returns a nullable object then no, there is no need to check if the injected field is `null`.

Comment: There are cases when it will return `null`, e.g. when the user signs out, in that case I get `Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method` so it does not feet to implement that, right?

Comment: In that case you have to mark your provider `@Nullable` as it may return a `null` object (that's what the error is about) and check the value after injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitly add `@Nullable` on your `@Provides` annotated method Dagger will [never inject `null` values](https://dagger.dev/api/2.23.2/dagger/Provides.html). If you want to inject a nullable object, then you need the `@Nullable` annotation there as well.

> Is it still necessary to check an object for nullity if it is initialized using Dagger2?

**No**, if your injection is set up correctly you will never have to deal with `null` values, unless you explicitly want to do so. If you still get a NullPointerException, then you have a problem with your Dagger setup which you need to fix.